# Как я могу отличить бессмысленную строку от осмысленной?

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения, строки

Допустим, я хочу получить текст из сообщения пользователя в том случае, если он не "мусорный". Допустим строку "***и как это понимать?***" допускаем, а "***ывалыавоговнржопа***" - нет, как реализовать?

Comment: Последняя часть второй строки, вроде как, тоже осмысленная.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg да и предпоследняя перед буквой «р» тоже...

Comment: ну смысл я передал - нужно получить максимально приближенную к грамотному описанию строку

Comment: @andreymal а если совместить первую строку со второй, так вообще полноценное предложение получаем.

Comment: Разбивать на слова и искать их в словаре?

Comment: Написать самообучаемый искусственный интелект и обучить его на книгах. Вряд-ли даже самый полный словарь тут поможет...

Comment: @NoSkill Лучше уж тогда на комментах, в книгах ошибок нет, и вот этого [Эррати́в](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Comment: Предлагаю такой вариант: фильтрация на базе двух факторов - проверки с леммизацией (а точнее, через поиск по основам слов, таким как "говн" и "жоп" в примере) и частотного анализа пар букв (например, "ыа" в словах осмысленных сообщений встречается крайне редко, если вообще встречается): оба фактора проверяются поиском по словарю, и не требуют нейросети (поэтому быстры и беспощадны) - просто вычисляем по ним "рейтинг пакостности сообщения", и сравниваем его с пороговым значением (регулирующим "жесткость" фильтра).

Comment: @yar85 Пролбема намного глубже. Считаестя ли мое пердложение осмылсеным?

Comment: @NoSkill, зависит от того что "скажет" проверка по второму фактору (основы стоп-слов отсутствуют, а значит если массив частот пар символов составлен хорошо/грамотно, то такое сообщение успешно пройдет через фильтр с умеренным пороговым значением). Я не просто так написал о вычислении рейтинга _сообщения_, а не отдельных слов или их частей... в этом рейтинге, доля "кривых" слов не перевесит долю "ровных", по-моему.

Comment: Еыасли жж вс сбщние тфак нпыссно, то в отфильтровку ему и дорога))) Ибо нефиг вызывать кровотечение из глаз невинных людей.

Comment: а как можно отфильтровать сообщение "Еыасли жж вс сбщние тфак нпыссно"? Код приведи, пожалуйста <3

Comment: _«Код приведи, пожалуйста»_ - это фактически "выполни работу за меня", а такие преложения не интересуют. Задача относительно сложная, и даже при том что в прошлом я писал подобное, методом "npm i, да пара строк кода" ее эффективно не решить: эффективное решение подразумевает и исследование нормы (стату собрать, тот же частотный словарь сформировать), и проектирование с учетом интеграций - только затем уж можно подумать о коде (он наименьшая из проблем).

Comment: В общем виде, вычисление рейтинга это банально суммирование в цикле (типа `rating = words.reduce((r, w) => r += ~~stopWords[wordBase(word)] + freqRating(word), 0)`, где `freqRating` почти аналогично вычисляется, в зависимости от типа структуры словаря)... хз какие трудности с кодом вообще могут возникнуть. А код частотного анализа, писать ясно-понятно сложно, но это общая (хоть и сложная) математика, и для этого вполне можно найти библиотеки (да-да, самостоятельно).

Comment: Естественно, реальный код должен учитывать и досрочное прерывание цикла если порог уже превышен (поэтому `reduce` не надо воспринимать буквально), но на высоком уровне (алгоритма) это всего лишь суммирование заранее обсчитанных статданных + интерфейсы прогр. взаимодействия (клейкод) и основная фишка заключается именно в данных... которых в вопросе даже отдаленно не представлено. С комплексными задачами нельзя просто взять строку и сказать "компьютер, я хочу, сделай вжух" :)

Answer (score 0):

Отправить в гугл. Если результатов много, то, скорее всего, строка осмысленная. Если результатов нет или очень мало, то наверняка абракадабра.

Comment: Напишите гуглу эту фразу задом-наперёд "ьтаминоп отэ как и".